# DataGridview column is showing only date values while on debugging it is showing date and time both

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have a Datagridview where the first column displays the date values .Now i need to export that into pdf but my pdf file consists of both date and time values in the same column that i dont want.

Here is the code..

```
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontTable));
                }
            }
        }
```

In the following line .

```
pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontTable));
```

On debugging i am getting date and time both for my date column .

How to solve this ..?

Comment: String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                        ShortTime

Comment: @Charlie I need only date to show into pdf table ..How to get it..?

Comment: String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"

Comment: @Charlie One more doubt where to add this snippet into my posted code?

Comment: You are adding values are in Datagridview? so replace the string while adding it

Comment: otherwise you will have to convert the string into Datetime and then use this code ..The better way will be to replace characters in strings starting index to ending index using substring

Comment: Kindly tell the format of date and time

Comment: @Charlie 2014-04-17 00:00:00   This is the format.How to add this into pdftable as i am creating pdf from the datagridview not adding this into datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontTable));
```

with

```
if(k==0)
{
  pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 12), fontTable));
}else
{
  pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(), fontTable));
}
```

i hope your problem will be solved

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.One more doubt actually date is my first column of every row .So how to apply this into my for loop code so that only first column of the row i.e date can be broken into substring.Thanks ..